# Increase size of individual connected component in a binary image (BW) when using regionprops

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using [imregionalmax](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregionalmax.html) to create a binary image `BW` that identifies the regional maxima in my image.

Next I want to use [regionprops](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) with property `WeightedCentroid` to identify the coordinates of the centroid centers in the image. However, [imregionalmax](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregionalmax.html) returns a binary image with very small connected components, which need to be increased in dimension to enable [regionprops](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) to weigh the centroid properly.

Possible solutions:

1. I believe the ideal situation would be to interrupt the [regionprops](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) operation at each iteration, and simply increase the size of the current connected component that it is working with by adding a couple of pixels in height and width to it.
2. In case this is not possible, a work around could be to split `BW` into an image stack with only a single connected component in each slice, expand each component by some pixels, and run [regionprops](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) individually on each image slice. This does not seem like a efficient way of solving this though.

Is there another more efficient way, and how would I implement that?

** I am aware that one way of increasing the connected components in `BW` is to use [imdilate](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html), but this will lead to unconnected components becoming connected.

** Another option is to use [bwmorph](http://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html) with property `thicken`, which performs very well, however in a case where multiple components are close together, the size cannot be increased in one direction and reduce the performance of `WeightedCentroid`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increase measurement accuracy by extending what you want to measure...

Centroid is simply the average of all region coordinates.
WeightedCentroid only takes intensities into account in case you don't have a binary image.

If you increase your object by whatever algorithm you like you risk shifting your centroid away from its true position!

Comment: In my case the binary image `BW` is only used as a "mask", and hence increasing this binary region will indeed improve accuracy, because a larger region on the image of interest will be used to find the centroid.

Comment: then you should mention that :)  I guess the best way would create separate masks from each blob and dilate them until their size is sufficient. Of course you then risk to mask other regions pixels which will again cause errors. So you have to define some rule how to cope with overlapping masks. You should provide sample images. Otherwise its impossible to give you a satisfactory answer.